# Problems with String Tokenizer

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

I have a set of 3 strings, each in different lines, which are integers separated by spaces.

```
1 1 2
3 4 4
4 5 5
```

I wanted to input them into a character array, and I used StringTokenizer in this manner:

```
for(int j=0;i<n1;i++){
  s2=bure.readLine();         
  st1=new StringTokenizer(s2);

  for(int k=0;k<n2;k++){
    a[j][k]=Integer.parseInt(st1.nextToken());
  }      
}
```

Where n1 and n2 are the number of rows and columns.

Comment: So wher it is giving problem

Comment: Great job. Go on with your program.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a typo in your code, first line - that 'i' should be 'j':

```
for(int j=0;j<n1;j++){
  s2=bure.readLine();         
  st1=new StringTokenizer(s2);

  for(int k=0;k<n2;k++){
    a[j][k]=Integer.parseInt(st1.nextToken());
  }      
}
```

Try this way. Also using st1.hasMoreElements() seems to be useful in case if you are receiving the data from an external source, and is not built by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringTokenizer st1;
    final int nrLines = 3;
    final int maxNrColumns = 3;
    int[][] a = new int[nrLines][maxNrColumns];
    for (int j = 0; j < nrLines; j++) {
        String s2 = sc.nextLine();
        st1 = new StringTokenizer(s2);
        for (int k = 0; k < maxNrColumns; k++) {
            if (st1.hasMoreElements()) {
                a[j][k] = Integer.parseInt(st1.nextToken());
            }
        }
    }
    // show the array
    for (int i = 0; i < nrLines; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < maxNrColumns; j++) {
            System.out.print(a[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```